# Send an SMS directly from a Service without SEND_SMS permission

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I pushed an app to the Play Store for Alpha testing and it got rejected because it uses the SEND_SMS permission.

I did some research and saw that the other way to "send" an SMS is to use an Intent. I tried to implement different ways presented in other posts on StackOverflow related to this matter but nothing worked as I wanted it to.

The closer I got was having the message saved as a draft in the Messages app.

The message is supposed to be sent when GPS coordinates continuously compared in a Foreground Service match within a certain radius.

This is one of the snippets of code I tried. This is from https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage.

```
fun composeMmsMessage(message: String) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
                data = Uri.parse("smsto:")  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
                putExtra("sms_body", message)
            }
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
```

Currently, my app automatically sends a message when this condition is met using SMSManager. However, I need to figure out a way to do achieve the same purpose without using the SEND_SMS permission.

In the case where this is not possible, what would be another approach to do this?

I would truly appreciate any help!

tldr: I already checked most of the other topics related to this issue on StackOverflow & I was not able to do what I want to do, send SMS automatically without user intervention without using the SEND_SMS permission.

Comment: You can't. You could use Intent to broadcast an SMS _intent_ but it will need user intervention. Sending automatic SMS unattended without SEND_SMS permission is obviously not possible.

Comment: Oh my. I'm currently developing app that can send message programatically. Didn't know google play now restricts it. :(

Comment: Thank you @shkschneider, I guess I will have to appeal Google's decision & hope it goes through!

Comment: Google restricts you from sending automated SMS without the persmission, that's all. From what I understand, yo DO need that permission. You just need to convince Google it's note a malicious app :)

Answer (score 0):

Google has already put restrictions to protect user privacy. 
Please check here to see the list of restricted permissions.[check this](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)